# Spring boot: Upgrading logback 1.2.12 to 1.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I use spring boot 2.7.12 and our company, for security reason, is asking to use at least the v1.3 of logback.
I see that spring-boot-starter-logging (v2.7.12) is using version 1.2.12 of logback-classic.

I would like to force the version to 1.3 but when I try to add this in parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
  ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have this error in child pom:

```
Missing artifact ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.3
```

I do not understand how to solve it.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried building parent pom with mvn clean install? if yes then try with  force (-U) for both parent and child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version change from 1.3 to 1.3.0 is required.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Link:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.3.0